# Combinatorial count of Min and Max of some functions

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, maxima-minima

Given $n$ functions $f_1, f_2, ..., f_n$ (say, simple linear over $\mathbb{R}$). How many different functions can one construct from them using only $\min$ and $\max$ operations? It is clear that the answer depends on the function system itself, but is there at least some reasonably good upper estimate of this number?

Do the following considerations make sense?

Let $M_n$ be the required number, $N_n$ be the number of different functions one can construct using only $\min$ and $\max$ and *using all n initial functions*. Then $M_n$ is less or equal to a sum of all $N_1, N_2, ..., N_n$ taken with correspondent binomial coefficients (select $k$ unique functions from $n$)

$$M_n \leqslant {\binom n 1} N_1 + {\binom n 2}N_2 + ... + {\binom n {n-1}}N_{n-1} + N_n,$$

$$N_n \leqslant 2n!N_{n-1}$$

The last formula follows from that we can take all $n$ given functions in any order ($n!$), then we can take exactly two $\min$ and $\max$ operations over any of $N_{n-1}$ last functions.

Is it correct? Is there any more precise estimate?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean you can take max/min on some number of these functions as well as compose max and min, so something like $\mathrm{max}(f_1,\mathrm{min}(f_2,f_3))$ is valid. If so, I don't think you can get any better than that. With a complicated enough set of functions, every arrangement of maxes and mins could be distinct.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thanks for your opinion

Comment: Assuming that every max/min composition is distinct (excluding, of course, max inside max or min inside min), I believe $N_n=2a_n$ in [this series](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C4%2C26%2C236&sort=&language=&go=Search). The $2$ comes from the fact that once you pick what the most outside function is (max or min), that determines what all functions inside must be.

Comment: I should clarify that my comments were referring to arbitrary functions. If we assume they're linear, you have much more structure to work with.

Comment: Note that $\min(f, \max(g,h)) \equiv \max(\min(f,g), \min(f,h))$, so do you count them as different functions or the same function?  Normally this would count as the same function...  IIRC MAX & MIN act like OR & AND of Boolean algebra.  The number of different Boolean functions of $n$ variables is $2^{2^n}$, but that requires the use of NOT, which you do not have here.  I think your question might be equivalent to how may different Boolean functions of $n$ variables you can create using only AND & OR, without NOT.

Comment: @antkam, thanks for a comment. I count only the first of them because every function is used only one time